# Aura :iteration and :if, WARNING: Performance degradation..

Tags: lightning, iteration, if, warning

I'm receiving a `WARNING: Performance degradation: Multiple items were set in iteration` message. This occurs in the code below when the `aura:if` element is there, but not when it isn't.

Each `group` contains a list of "`entries`". I simply want to hide the entire group and associated markup (more has been removed for clarity) when there are no `entries` for that group.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.groups}" var="group">
    <span> <!-- Workaround for a bug in Lightning, leave this tag around the :if -->
        <aura:if isTrue="{!group.entries.length > 0}">
            {group.name}
            <aura:iteration items="{!group.entries}" var="entry">
                {!entry.Description__c}
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:if>
    </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

The attributes are only being set once, which seems to be verified by the fact that this error only occurs when the `aura:if` is involved. This makes me think that it is something to do with the interaction between the `:if` and the `:iteration`. Is anyone aware of the cause of this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that using an `:if` in an `:iteration` is not recommended. From the [salesforce developer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_conditional_markup.htm):

> Here are some use cases where you should consider alternatives to `<aura:if>`:
>
> You need to nest conditional logic or use conditional logic in an iteration

It is stated that this is for performance reasons, which echoes the warning being given.

An alternative method, such as hiding the elements via CSS, is recommended. Note that `class="{! expr ? 'class1' : 'class2'}"` works and so `aura:if` can be avoided in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the browser console, u'll see that SFDC CRM application code itself triggers lots of

```
     "WARNING: Performance degradation: Multiple items were set in iteration"
```

, so I think it's not an important warning -> can be ignored :)

For example, such warning is triggered each time you click on a tab 'dropdown arrow', which is 100% SFDC code.